# How would I do this JOIN in Rails?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `message_users`
    LEFT JOIN `messages` ON message_users.message_id = messages.id
    WHERE (message_users.user_id = 1 AND message_users.hidden = 0)  AND message_users.last_read_at > messages.updated_at
    ORDER BY messages.updated_at DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

How would I pull that off with proper Rails joins/includes/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't typically load all the data from multiple tables into one model in rails.  More common is to replace the **joins** below with **include**, which will preload the associated model so you hit the cache when calling **message.message_users**.  At any rate, this should duplicate what your sql was doing, as long as there are no column name clashes between **messages** and **messages_users**.

If you don't need the data from messages_users after the query is performed, you can remove the **select** fragment.

```
  Message.find(:all, 
               :joins=>:message_users, 
               :select=>"message_users.*, messages.*",
               :conditions=>['message_users.user_id = ? and message_users.hidden = ? and message_users.last_read_at > messages.updated_at', 1,0],
               :order=>"messages.updated_at desc",
               :limit=>20)
```

There's a good screencast about the difference between **joins** and **include** [here](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/181_include_vs_joins.mov)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly and I appreciate the additional info.

Comment: No problem - on 2nd thought I'd just leave it as :joins unless you really need to access the message_users data after the query.